# name of a concept with data persistence

Tags: java, database, model-view-controller, persistence

I am looking a name of a concept, where you can configure
any type of persistence methods like RDBMS, XML Databases, RESTful APIs or a formatted file like CSV file to a programming language, such as Java.
I am quite sure that this concept has a name, but I just can't remember what it's called...

It's similar to "DataSource" in CakePHP, but as I mentioned, it wouldn't be restricted only to RDBMS.

Does anyone got an idea?
EDIT: and know an actual implementation of this concept to Java?

Answer (score 1):

I think "Data Source" already describes it very well. And data sources in CakePHP are *not* limited to just RDBMS. See https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/tree/2.0/Model/Datasource

I do no think there is a real name for that, what you're looking for is more a pattern and I think this level of abstraction can be approached by using different ways or patterns. Check how CakePHP or any other good framework is doing it or directly check the Spring framework for java. If you want to write your own abstraction layer lets inspire you be them.

Comment: thanks for the answer. ah, I didn't know that Datasource in CakePHP is also able to use other than RDBMS. I am so sure that the implementation exist as a collegue was using it at 5 years ago. And of course, He doesn't remember anything about it either...

Answer (score 0):

How about DataServiceProvider and Abstract/Persist through one of the DataAdapters "types"

Which your business objects, or application services can locate this via a common service locator.

We have a similar implementation, though practically it is not being used much as people would prefer their own tools to source data for other data types.